# vtkMFC build error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, vtk

I tried to build vtkMFC project available in vtk-5.8.0\VTK\Examples\GUI\Win32\vtkMFC.
When I built that I got errors as , can't find vtkMFCWindow.h and vtkMFCConfigure.h files.
I included them in the projects taken from, vtk-5.8.0\VTK\GUISupport\MFC folder.
After that I got an error message as, ">LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'vtkMFC.lib".

When I search for the lib, I could not find it. I rebuilt the VTK.sln again but the lib was not there.
So I guessed  I may want to build the project in, vtk-5.8.0\VTK\GUISupport\MFC as well.
But when I try to build it, I get a cmake error as , "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (VTK_ADD_LIBRARY):
Unknown CMake command "VTK_ADD_LIBRARY"."

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vtkMFC is a build option in CMake when you compile VTK for the first time. I take it you are using Windows so you may be interested in this pdf that describes how to build. The option you need to check is in CMake and is searchable under VTK_USE_MFC - this builds the vtkMFC.lib library that your program is looking for.

http://vtkblog.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/install-build-vtk-from-source-in-visual.html

Comment: Thanks @user1310934. I checked VTK_USE_MFC option, but I am still getting the error. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using to build?

Comment: I am using VS 2008. I built it finally by configuring Cmake properly. My problem was I could not find the options  VTK_USE_MFC, VTK_USE_GUI in cmake, but I found it under the advanced options. Thanks a lot for the help.